# Is there a native recyclerview workable on both Android and IOS in (react-native)

Tags: react-native, android-recyclerview, uicollectionview, react-native-flatlist

I have a large list with complex calculations and `Flatlist` is really makes my app slow and responsive goes down when `scrolling`. Also I find and used lots of packages on the Internet but they works to well only with specific `height`, but my `items height` is dynamic.

I used all useful way for `Flatlist`, but still scrolling is slow, even some time crashes my app, Can you please show me a native `updated` recycler list view for react-native or is there a best way for this situations.

**What happens to my List?**

It is a chat like app, so there is images, text messages, videos and stickers, also some status like `seen` and `delevered`, also when messages get 'seen' that particular message items update as a single item for example last single message has seen, so it will be updated.

**My Current Code with 380 items:**

```
<FlatList data={arrayItems}
  initialNumToRender={1}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Virtualized List https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#example?

Comment: I am using flatlist

Comment: You can try Virtualized List. Flat List is built using this only. It can help with optimizations. Can you please add some code?

Answer (score 2):

FlatList is the counterpart of Android Studio RecyclerView

there might me various reasons why your Flatlist data rendering is slow.
1) One way to resolve this if you have huge data is to fetch the data in parts for example you can initially fetch and render 20 [initialNumToRender](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender) list items then when the user is scrolling call an api to fetch next 20 records using [onEndReachedThreshold](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold)  to call [onEndReached](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached) to get the next batch of data.

2) if you are using class components to display the flatlist its better to use PureComponent if the data is huge.

3) use Functional component for speed.

Also if you are dealing with huge amount of data its better to use state management library like redux to store the data.

Comment: Thank you All used All your saying already, `initialNumToRender={1}` and paginated with 25 item for every `end of reached threshold` also I am using functional component, also I check using useMemo and memo to avoid un neccessary rendering, but still is too slow.

Comment: All is basic with 300 items

Comment: `<FlatList
        data={arrayItems}
        initialNumToRender={1}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
  />`

Comment: So in general the FlatList uses RecyclerView on Android and UICollectionView on iOS?